# requests module gets different content than is on the page

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, python-requests

I am getting completely different content than viewing source on the page shows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&start=740"

r = requests.get(URL)
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

"Apply with" in content

for span in spans:
    try:
        if "Apply" in span.string:
            print(span.string)
    except:
        pass
```

There is no "Apply" in the spans, and no "Apply with" on the page. The only way I can identify what I want is the "Apply with" part

[image]

[image]
How do I make the requests module return the same html I get when I visit the page? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *you cannot expect `requests` bring you the same exact page as you see in the browser developer tools* since `requests` would only retrieve the initial HTML page without executing any javascript, without making any additional requests required to load the page - in other words, **`requests` is not a browser**.

About this particular case, I actually see "Easily apply" instead of "Apply with your Indeed resume". It looks like you are logged into Indeed in the browser.

And I see these "Easily apply" elements in both `requests` response and in the browser:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> URL = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&start=740"
>>> 
>>> r = requests.get(URL, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"})
>>> content = r.text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> for span in soup.find_all("span", class_="iaLabel"):
...     print(span.text)
... 
 Easily apply
 Easily apply
 Easily apply
 Easily apply
 Easily apply
```

---

If you want to be as close to the browser as possible in your automation, then, well, use a real browser - you can control real browsers like Firefox or Chrome, or headless PhantomJS, via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: that might be true, but for this particular page, the only link of value is the one that says "Apply with your indeed resume"